# Combining two (boolean) categorical factors two new one

Tags: r

Given two boolean, categorical factors, how can I get the combination of them as a third category?

```
> my_data <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                        b = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
> my_data
  a b
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 1 0
4 1 1
5 1 1
```

I want to add a new category, with the combination of a and b so that:

```
> my_data
  a b c
1 0 0 1
2 0 1 2
3 1 0 3
4 1 1 4
5 1 1 4
```

I didn't want to be lazy and thought about it for myself:

```
my_data$c <- as.numeric(as.factor(my_data$a + 1 + (my_data$b + 1) * 2))
```

This comes close, but I don't find it particularly elegant.
Therefore, any nicer solution in base R would be appreciated.
There are certainly also packages likes `reshape2` which would offer similar functionality.

Comment: What is the calculation logic for `c` ?

Comment: Why do you have to convert to `factor` then `numeric` if it can be directly calculated as `my_data$c <- my_data$a + 1 + (my_data$b + 1) * 2`?

Comment: assuming no cases are missing the logic is: 2*a + b + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option with base R:

```
r <- rle(do.call(paste0, my_data))
r$values <- seq_along(r$values)
my_data$c <- inverse.rle(r)
```

The result:

```
> my_data
  a b c
1 0 0 1
2 0 1 2
3 1 0 3
4 1 1 4
5 1 1 4
```

A shorter version of above code:

```
r <- rle(do.call(paste0, my_data))$lengths
my_data$c <- rep(seq_along(r), r)
```

Comment: I thought about something `paste`ing the 2 columns to a third one. Actually a very nice solution, which even works with non-boolean vectors (which was of course not part of the question).

Answer (score 6):

The following logic seems to be enough for all the cases you have provided.

```
my_data$c <- with(my_data, 2*a + b + 1)

my_data
  a b c
1 0 0 1
2 0 1 2
3 1 0 3
4 1 1 4
5 1 1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

The expected output in the question is just the input seen as numbers in base 2 converted to base 10 plus 1.
So, looking for a function that converts from base 2 to base 10 I have found the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411380/convert-binary-vector-to-decimal).

So it's a matter of `apply()`ing that function to the data frame.

```
apply(my_data, 1, bitsToInt) + 1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 4
```

Comment: This solution wins of course the price for shortness. It works very well and reliably for boolean vectors. I hope you don't mind if I say that it might be slightly obfuscated for beginners (especially if they are not computer scientists).

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki No, I don't mind at all. In fact, it seems that not many noticed it, what is obvious to some is not to others. And this is independent of one's rep.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% mutate(c = group_indices(.,a,b))
#   a b c
# 1 0 0 1
# 2 0 1 2
# 3 1 0 3
# 4 1 1 4
# 5 1 1 4
```

A base equivalent:

```
temp <- unique(my_data)
temp$c <- seq(nrow(temp))
merge(my_data,temp)
#   a b c
# 1 0 0 1
# 2 0 1 2
# 3 1 0 3
# 4 1 1 4
# 5 1 1 4
```

Comment: I actually like this solution, it is general and as far as I can see would even work with non-boolean vectors (which was not part of my question).

Comment: Yes, it should be quite general, it may not work with list columns though. The perfect fit to your case in my opinion is Rui's answer, as what you're really doing is translating binary to decimal. Current chosen solution will not be robust for characters or numbers > 9.